# Heisenberg Representation of Dirac Equation Quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am wondering exactly how to apply the following method to the Dirac equation (and even electromagnetism if it is easy to type up). It is a method of deriving the momentum-space Hamiltonian without using the explicit Hamiltonian, and is a lot easier than working with quadratic terms. Could somebody be so kind as to help me by showing me how to do the same thing in one or both of those cases as the following?

For a scalar field, we have in general that

$$\hat{\Psi}(x') = e^{i(a_{\mu}\hat{P}^{\mu} + \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_{\mu \nu}J^{\mu \nu})} \hat{\Psi}(x) e^{-i(a_{\mu}\hat{P}^{\mu} + \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_{\mu \nu}J^{\mu \nu})}$$

holds, so translating the operator

$$\hat{\Psi}(\vec{x},t) =  \hat{\Psi}^+(\vec{x},t) + \hat{\Psi}^-(\vec{x},t) = \int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}} \ \hat{a}(\vec{k},t)e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} + \int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}} \ \hat{b}^+(\vec{k},t)e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}$$

in time we see

$$\hat{\Psi}(\vec{x},t + dt) = e^{i\hat{H}dt} \hat{\Psi} e^{-i\hat{H}dt}$$

is it's unitarily equivalent time displacement. But you know that

$$\hat{\Psi}(\vec{x},t + dt) = (1 + i\hat{H}dt)\hat{\Psi}(1 - i\hat{H}dt) = \hat{\Psi}(\vec{x},t) - i[\hat{\Psi},\hat{H}]dt$$

produces

$$\frac{\partial \hat{\Psi}}{\partial t}dt = - i[\hat{\Psi},\hat{H}]dt$$

which, when expanded, looks like

$$\frac{\partial \hat{\Psi}^+}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial \hat{\Psi}^-}{\partial t}dt =  - i[\hat{\Psi}^+,\hat{H}]dt - i[\hat{\Psi}^-,\hat{H}]dt$$

so that

$$\frac{\partial \hat{\Psi}^+}{\partial t} = - i[\hat{\Psi}^+,\hat{H}]$$

$$ \frac{\partial \hat{\Psi}^-}{\partial t} = - i[\hat{\Psi}^-,\hat{H}]$$

Fourier expanded

$$\int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}} (- i \omega ) \ \hat{a}(\vec{k},t)e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}}  = \int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}} (-i) [\hat{a}(\vec{k},t),\hat{H}]e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}}$$

$$ \int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}} \ (i \omega ) \hat{b}^+(\vec{k},t)e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}} = \int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}} (- i)[\hat{b}^+(\vec{k},t),\hat{H}]e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}$$

means the equations

$$  \omega  \ \hat{a}(\vec{k},t)= [\hat{a}(\vec{k},t),\hat{H}]$$

$$  \omega  \hat{b}^+(\vec{k},t) =  - [\hat{b}^+(\vec{k},t),\hat{H}]$$

should hold.

These equations almost immediately imply, simply by observation, that choosing

$H = \int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}}' \omega'  \hat{a}^+(\vec{k}',t) \hat{a}(\vec{k}',t)$

in the first case, and

$H = \int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}}' \omega'  \hat{b}(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}^+(\vec{k}',t)$

in the second case, will produce the right answer, because of the commutation relations

$$ [\hat{a},\hat{a}'^+\hat{a}'] = \delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')\hat{a}$$

$$ [\hat{a}^+,\hat{a}'^+\hat{a}'] = - \delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')\hat{a}$$

Therefore

$$\hat{\mathrm{H}} = \int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}} ' \omega (\hat{a}^+(\vec{k}',t)\hat{a}(\vec{k}',t) + \hat{b}(\vec{k}',t)\hat{b}^+(\vec{k}',t))$$

This same method gives us the momentum, angular momentum and charge very easy, I hope it applies to the Dirac equation, electromagnetism and even supersymmetry to avoid those big calculations. Hope to hear from you.

Comment: For the Dirac eq. I think all you need to try it yourself is listed in Prob.6, pg.3 (also see Probs.4,5,7) here: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/oh3.pdf. Does it help?

Comment: @udrv Pretty sure this is different to Tong's example.  If you can actually find a Heisenberg representation for the Dirac equation and it is correct, which it is
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/heisenberg-equation-of-motion-for-fermions.235116/#post-2955366
I'm thinking you should be able to do exactly what I did above but using equation 7.7 here
http://eduardo.physics.illinois.edu/phys582/582-chapter7.pdf
Seems like it really should be possible to do the above calculation in the Dirac case, but the spinors and gamma's really confuse me when I write it out :\

Comment: I didn't mean Tong solves your question in his example. I meant "all info you need to transpose your procedure onto the Dirac case is listed there": you have the field operators, the spinors, the commutation and closure relations. If you prefer, use the equivalents in the ref. you mention. Simply apply them as you did above for the scalar field with a little care in handling the spinors.

Comment: It looks like a straightforward analogy and the explicit form of the Hamiltonian shouldn't bother you. Once you have the Heisenberg eqs. for the $b_{\vec p}^s$ and   $c_{\vec p}^s$, it suffices to assume the Hamiltonian is bilinear in the latter.

Comment: @udrv I either get the exact same thing as above all the way through, an incomprehensible jumble, or the same thing apart from anti-commutation relations which does not eliminate terms, trying Tong's identities. This should work without the explicit Hamiltonian it's just not falling out when you try to copy the above calculation as much as humanly possible right now :(

Comment: Actually it does work, but too long for a comment. I put everything in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the Dirac field operators, 
$$
\hat{\psi}_D(\vec{x},t) =  \hat{\psi}_D^+(\vec{x},t) + \hat{\psi}_D^-(\vec{x},t) =  \sum_{s=1}^2 {\int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}} \; \hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)u_s(\vec{k})e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} + \int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}} \ \hat{c}_s^\dagger(\vec{k},t)v_s(\vec{k})e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}}
$$ 
where now $u_s(\vec{k})$, $v_s(\vec{k})$ are 4-component spinors and operators $\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)$, $\hat{c}_s(\vec{k},t)$ satisfy the anticommutation relations
$$
\{\hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t), \hat{b}^\dagger_s(\vec{k},t) \} = \{\hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t), \hat{c}^\dagger_s(\vec{k},t) \} = (2\pi)^3\delta_{rs}\delta(\vec{k}'-\vec{k})\\
\{\hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t), \hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t) \} = \{\hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t), \hat{c}_s(\vec{k},t) \} = 0
$$
Applying your time-translation procedure to the positive and negative frequency parts of field as before, yields again
$$
\frac{\partial \hat{\psi}_D^+}{\partial t} = - i[\hat{\psi}_D^+,\hat{H}], \;\;\; \frac{\partial \hat{\psi}_D^-}{\partial t} = - i[\hat{\psi}_D^-,\hat{H}]
$$
and after identifying terms in the Fourier expansion,
$$  
\omega  \hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)u_s(\vec{k})= [\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)u_s(\vec{k}),\hat{H}] \\
\omega  \hat{c}_s^\dagger(\vec{k},t)v_s(\vec{k}) =  - [\hat{c}_s^\dagger(\vec{k},t)v_s(\vec{k}),\hat{H}]
$$
Now assume that the Hamiltonian is only bilinear in the $\hat{b}_r(\vec{k},t)u_r(\vec{k})$ and $\hat{c}_r(\vec{k},t)v_r(\vec{k})$. Straightforward algebra will show that terms of the form $\left(\hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k},t)u^\dagger_r(\vec{k})\right) \left(\hat{c}_{r'}(\vec{k},t)v_{r'}(\vec{k})\right)$ and $\left(\hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k},t)u^\dagger_r(\vec{k})\right) \left(\hat{b}_{r'}(\vec{k},t)v_{r'}(\vec{k})\right)$ cannot contribute if the above commutation relations are to hold. So $H$ can have only terms of the form $\left(\hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k},t)u^\dagger_r(\vec{k})\right) \left(\hat{b}_{r'}(\vec{k},t)u_{r'}(\vec{k})\right)$ and $\left(\hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k},t)v^\dagger_r(\vec{k})\right) \left(\hat{c}_{r'}(\vec{k},t)v_{r'}(\vec{k})\right)$. But the spinor closure relations 
$$
u^\dagger_r(\vec{k})u_{r'}(\vec{k}) = 2 \omega \delta_{rs}, \;\;\; v^\dagger_r(\vec{k})v_{r'}(\vec{k}) = 2 \omega\delta_{rr'}
$$
further reduce acceptable terms to $2\omega \hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k},t)\hat{b}_r(\vec{k},t)$ and $2 \omega \hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k},t)\hat{c}_r(\vec{k},t)$ and eventually leave the Hamiltonian as
$$ 
H = \sum_{r=1}^2{\int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}}' \omega'  \left[ \hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t) + \hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t)\right]}
$$
Indeed, now we have
$$
[\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)u_s(\vec{k}),\hat{H}]  \equiv  \sum_{r=1}^2{\int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}}' \omega'  \left[\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)u_s(\vec{k}), \hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t) + \hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t)\right]} = \\
= \sum_{r=1}^2{\int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}}' \omega'  \left[\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t), \hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t)\right]u_s(\vec{k})} + \sum_{r=1}^2{\int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}}' \omega'  \left[\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t), \hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t)\right]u_s(\vec{k})}
$$
and using the anticommutation relations for the $\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)$, $\hat{c}_s(\vec{k},t)$,
$$
\left[\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t), \hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t)\right] = \hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)\hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t) - \hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t) = \\
= (2\pi)^3\delta_{rs}\delta(\vec{k}'-\vec{k})\hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t) - \hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t)\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t) \hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t) + \hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t)\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t) \hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t) = \\
= (2\pi)^3\delta_{rs}\delta(\vec{k}'-\vec{k})\hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t) 
$$
$$
\left[\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t), \hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t)\right] = \hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)\hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t) - \hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t) = \\
= - \hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t)\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t) \hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t) + \hat{c}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t)\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t) \hat{c}_r(\vec{k}',t) = 0
$$
Substituting gives, as expected,
$$
\sum_{r=1}^2{\int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}}' \omega'  \left[\hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t), \hat{b}^\dagger_r(\vec{k}',t) \hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t)\right]u_s(\vec{k})} = \sum_{r=1}^2{\int d^3 \tilde{\mathrm{k}}' \omega' (2\pi)^3\delta_{rs}\delta(\vec{k}'-\vec{k})\hat{b}_r(\vec{k}',t) u_s(\vec{k})}  = \omega  \hat{b}_s(\vec{k},t)u_s(\vec{k})
$$
And similarly for $[\hat{c}^\dagger_s(\vec{k},t)v^\dagger_s(\vec{k}),\hat{H}]$.

Comment: Really nice, fear of spinors tripped me up, thank you!

Comment: Great, welcome :)